# How to identify what parts of the allocated virtual memory a process is using

Tags: windows, 64-bit, virtual-memory, readprocessmemory

I want to be able to search through the allocated memory of a process (say you open notepad and type “HelloWorld” then ran the search looking for the string “HelloWorld”). For 32bit applications this is not a problem but for 64 bit applications the large quantity of allocated virtual memory takes hours to search through.

Obviously the vast majority of applications are not utilising the full amount of virtual memory allocated. I can identify the areas in memory allocated to each process with VirtualQueryEX and read them with ReadProcessMemory but when it comes to 64 bit applications this still takes hours to complete.

Does anyone know of any resources or any methods that could be used to help narrow down the amount of memory to be searched?

Answer (score 2):

It is important that you only scan proper memory. If you just scanned from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFFF it would take at least 5 seconds in most processes. You can skip bad regions of memory by checking the memory page settings by using VirtualQueryEx. This will retrieve a MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION which will define the state of that memory region.

If the MemoryBasicInformation.state is not MEM_COMMIT then it is bad memory
If the MBI.Protect is PAGE_NOACCESS you also want to skip this memory.
If VirtualQuery fails then you skip to the next region.

In this manner it should only take 0-2 seconds to scan the memory on your average process because it is only scanning good memory.

```cpp
char* ScanEx(char* pattern, char* mask, char* begin, intptr_t size, HANDLE hProc)
{
    char* match{ nullptr };
    SIZE_T bytesRead;
    DWORD oldprotect;
    char* buffer{ nullptr };
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    mbi.RegionSize = 0x1000;//

    VirtualQueryEx(hProc, (LPCVOID)begin, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));

    for (char* curr = begin; curr < begin + size; curr += mbi.RegionSize)
    {
        if (!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, curr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))) continue;
        if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT || mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS) continue;

        delete[] buffer;
        buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize];

        if (VirtualProtectEx(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect))
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead);
            VirtualProtectEx(hProc, mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, oldprotect, &oldprotect);

            char* internalAddr = ScanBasic(pattern, mask, buffer, (intptr_t)bytesRead);

            if (internalAddr != nullptr)
            {
                //calculate from internal to external
                match = curr + (internalAddr - buffer);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] buffer;
    return match;
}
```

ScanBasic is just a standard comparison function which compares your pattern against the buffer.

Second, if you know the address is relative to a module, only scan the address range of that module, you can get the size of the module via ToolHelp32Snapshot.  If you know it's dynamic memory on the heap, then only scan the heap.  You can get all the heaps also with ToolHelp32Snapshot and TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST.

You can make a wrapper for this function as well for scanning the entire address space of the process might look something like this

```
char* Pattern::Ex::ScanProc(char* pattern, char* mask, ProcEx& proc)
{
    unsigned long long int kernelMemory = IsWow64Proc(proc.handle) ? 0x80000000 : 0x800000000000;

    return Scan(pattern, mask, 0x0, (intptr_t)kernelMemory, proc.handle);
}
```